# Can't get to elements which there are in iframe of Customer.io

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have Customer.io account for emails which collects emails from test server.
There in an iframe where there needed elements. But I can't get to them. If I use:

```
page.in_iframe(xpath: "//iframe[contains(@class, 'ember-view')]") do |frame|
  page.cell_element(xpath: "//td[contains(text(), 'Order Confirmation')]", frame: frame).when_present(30)
end
```

Then I get next error:

```
SyntaxError: (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
.../iframe[contains(@class, 'ember-view')]').td(identifier)
...                               ^
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...e[contains(@class, 'ember-view')]').td(identifier)
...                               ^
(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
...ntains(@class, 'ember-view')]').td(identifier)
...
```

And if I use this:

```
page.in_iframe(xpath: "//iframe[contains(@class, ember)]") do |frame|
  page.cell_element(xpath: "//td[contains(text(), 'Order Confirmation')]", frame: frame).when_present(30)
end
```

Then I don't get this error but element couldn't be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be with the parsing of the iframe XPath string. I do not understand why the interpreter is having problems, but here are some solutions:

For the first example, switch to using single quotes as the outer part of the String:

```
page.in_iframe(xpath: '//iframe[contains(@class, "ember-view")]') do |frame|
  page.cell_element(xpath: "//td[contains(text(), 'Order Confirmation')]", frame: frame).when_present(30)
end
```

For the second example, you do need to quote the attribute value. If you want to stick with double-quotes for the String, you can escape the inner double-quotes:

```
page.in_iframe(xpath: "//iframe[contains(@class, \"ember\")]") do |frame|
  page.cell_element(xpath: "//td[contains(text(), 'Order Confirmation')]", frame: frame).when_present(30)
end
```

Alternatively, you might want to consider avoiding the XPath problem by using other locators:

```
page.in_iframe(class: 'ember-view') do |frame|
  page.cell_element(text: /Order Confirmation/, frame: frame).when_present(30)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the goals of Watir is to never have to use XPath.

Consider rewriting your locator with regular expressions like this:

```
@browser.iframe(class: /ember/).td(text: /Order Confirmation/)
```

Comment: I'm not saying yours doesn't work, just that using XPath with Watir isn't good practice in general.

Answer (score 0):

I've found another way:

```
@browser.iframe(xpath: "//iframe[contains(@class,'ember')]").td(xpath: "//td[contains(text(), 'Order Confirmation')]")
```

Because that examples don't want to work. Don't know why.

But thanks Justin: